# Can I use more than two XSLT transformation in a ESB Proxy (WSO2)? There is a limit for that?

Tags: xslt, proxy, wso2, transformation, wso2-esb

I need to use 3 XSLT transformations in my ESB Proxy (Wso2) but it doesn't works.

When I try to use 2 XSLT and 1 Payload Factory (instead of the second XSLT), proxy works correctly: do the first XSLT, call first service, do the second XSLT, call second service, do third XSLT and respond correctly, ending the flow.

But when I change this Payload Factory for XSLT transformation, the proxy do the first XSLT, call first service, do the second XSLT, skip the second Call and try to do the third XSLT, but stop working.

If I take a look at my log file, it shows that the server is doing the transformations correctly (I put some logs to see that, and the transformations are correct). So, I believe that my transformations are right.

My proxy is something link that:

```
<proxy name="Proxy1" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable" transports="http https" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
  <target>
    <inSequence>
      <xslt key="conf:transformation/TransformSubmitPartnerRequestToFirstExternalServiceRequest.xsl" source="//SubmitPartnerRequest">
      </xslt>
      <call>
        <endpoint key="FirstExternalServiceEndpoint"/>
      </call>
      <xslt key="conf:transformation/transformFirstExternalServiceResponseToSecondExternalServiceRequest.xsl" source="//FirstExternalServiceResponse">
      </xslt>
      <call>
        <endpoint key="CLMServiceEndpoint"/>
      </call>
      <send/>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence>
      <xslt key="conf:transformation/transformSecondExternalServiceResponseToSubmitPartnerResponse.xsl" source="//SecondExternalServiceResponse"/>
      <send/>
    </outSequence>
    <faultSequence/>
  </target>
  <publishWSDL key="gov:wsdl/ServiceV1.wsdl">
    <resource key="gov:wsdl/Information.xsd" location="./Information.xsd"/>
  </publishWSDL>
</proxy>
```

An example of my transformations:

```
<!-- First transformation: TransformSubmitPartnerRequestToFirstExternalServiceRequest.xsl -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="//SubmitPartnerRequest">
    <Request>
        <!-- info here... -->
        </Request>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Is there something wrong with my code?
Can I use more than 2 XSLT transformations in my ESB proxy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to send properties to my second XSLT transformation, and this was the problem.

I changed it and now my proxy is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In your inSequence, we can find :

- xslt
- call endpoint
- xslt
- call endpoint
- send  --> this send without any endpoint will send back the current message as a response

Your outSequence should not be executed : remove it and add it's xslt inside inSequence before last send mediator

Comment: I put the last XSLT inside inSequence, but the problem continues... My outSequence is empty..

Comment: use log level="full" between the 3rd xslt and the last send : can you see the result of your transformation ? if not, can you find errors in wso2-esb-error.log ?